# Change Gradle Android buildDir not working with Gradle Android plugin 1.5

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

In order to generate output in a specific directory I have in my sub project build.gradle file :

```
if (rootProject.hasProperty('buildDir')) {
    buildDir = rootProject.ext.buildDir + '/' + name
}
```

It was working with Gradle Android plugin 1.2.0 but it is not working anymore when Gradle Android plugin 1.5.0

I use Gradle 2.2.1

Anything changed ?

Comment: I am stuck on this as well. Also using 2.2.1

Comment: Btw, bug reported : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=197601

Comment: I gave up and just passed in the buildDir on the command line: -PbuildDir="path/to/the/directory"